# nodejs require multiple files

Tags: node.js, body-parser

can some one explain, I am confused by the bodyparser library in nodeJS.
There is this line

var deprecate = require('depd')('body-parser')

If I look for IDE definitions for deprecate, it points to the depd library, but I am not sure what the second (body-parser) parameter doing here?

Answer (score 1):

The line you ask about "activates" depd library for body-parser library.
You can get more details here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/depd
Anyway, if you use express, body-parser is embedded and you do not need to require it. For more details: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Answer (score -1):

All you're doing is calling a function twice. You need to use the "&&" operator to run seperate functions:

```
  var deprecate = require('depd') && require('body-parser')
```

Comment: This statement: `require('depd')('body-parser')`, executes `require("depd")` and then calls the exported result from that and passes it the argument `"body-parser"`.  For example, you can do the same with Express as in `const app = require("express")()`.  In fact, that form can be used for any module that exports a function as its main export.  The OP's code is equivalent to two separate statements: `const depd = require("depd");` followed by `depd("body-parser");`

Comment: I thought you wanted to run the function twice because that was in the title and your question was short.